# PHP Cookies are not set by websocket handshake

Tags: php, cookies, websocket, handshake

I created a PHP websocket server and connected with a webbrowser to it. Everything works fine. Now I want to sent some cookie information to the websocket server, but the cookies and never send with the headers. I really don't have any idea why the cookies aren't included in the request headers. (The cookie is set and not empty when echo'ing with php in index.php)

This is the request and response header

**request**

```
GET ws://127.0.0.1:9000/chat HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9000
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 2nR9SZYdLOG32fpV6eJ/wA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

**response**

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: QecMAdsem/PYww1pYkyjD+79OmM=
```

**handshake**

```
// do handyshake: (hybi-10)
$secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
$secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
$response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
$response.= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
$response.= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
$response.= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " . $secAccept . "\r\n";
```

**Way of connecting to server in client (javascript)**

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:9000/chat');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are loading your page from `localhost`, but connecting your WebSocket to `127.0.0.1`.
Those two are considered two different domains, so they don't share cookies.

You need to connect your WebSocket as:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000/chat');
```

Or better, if you don't hardcode the hostname:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://'+location.hostname+':9000/chat');
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for the reply and for the answer! It is working now. Pretty strange, I always thought localhost is equal to 127.0.0.1 so it doesn't matter which one I used, but it turns out it not the same.